# Jpackage with ControlsFX

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx, jpackage

I’m having some issues including Controlsfx when using Jpackage.

I have set up a project in IntelliJ with JavaFX using a Archetype from Maven Central. Works fine with JavaFX in IntelliJ. I can package it with Maven (from IntelliJ) and use JPackage for making an exe-installer, that also works fine. I’m using this command with JPackage:

```
jpackage --input C:\...\target --add-modules javafx.controls --module-path C:\...\openjfx-20.0.1_windows-x64_bin-jmods\javafx-jmods-20.0.1 --module-path --win-console --dest c:\outputs --main-jar tests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --main-class tests.App
```

Now I want to incorporate ControlsFX so I download the ControlsFX .JAR from Maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/11.1.2IntelliJ
In IntelliJ I add it as a Module. All fine, I wan use ControlsFX in my project.

Now I want to make an exe-installer (like above without ControlsFX) so I add ControlsFX to my JPackage command:

```
jpackage --input C:\...\target --add-modules javafx.controls,controlsfx --module-path C:\...\openjfx-20.0.1_windows-x64_bin-jmods\javafx-jmods-20.0.1 --module-path C:\..\controlsfx --win-console --dest c:\test --main-jar tests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --main-class tests.App
```

When running the command I get this:

java.lang.module.FindException: Module controlsfx not found

I know my issue is related to the command I pass to JPackage but cant figure out what is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by @Slaw in comments below, you have used the wrong module name. You can confirm the module name of a jar by viewing the [module definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616520/list-modules-in-jar-file/46617033#comment134547336_46617033). This tells you the name of the module to use with jpackage eg `org.controlsfx.controls` or will print `No module descriptor found.  Derived automatic module.` if a non module jar:

```
jar --file=controlsfx.jar --describe-module
org.controlsfx.controls@11.1.2 jar:file:///c:/dev/mods/controlsfx.jar!/module-info.class
... plus details of exports
```

The `jpackage` command will use `jlink` internally to build a runtime image that contains all the modules listed:

```
jpackage --input myinput --add-modules javafx.controls,org.controlsfx.controls --module-path c:\xyz...\javafx-jmods-NN --module-path c:\abc...\controlsfx.jar  --dest myoutput {otherargs}
```

After installation you can check which modules are in the installed runtime with:

```
 C:\Program Files\XYZ\runtime\bin\java --list-modules
 ...
 javafx.controls@somever
 ...
 org.controlsfx.controls@somever
```

Alternatively you can use a jar (module or non module) with `jpackage` by copying the jar into your target release structure somewhere under the `--input` directory. Then it will be picked up as a classpath jar dependency (inside the release directories) rather than as a module dependency (inside the runtime image as above).

You can check if a jar was added as as classpath dependency by looking at the generated `{launcher}.cfg`, it should contain a line:

```
 app.classpath=$APPDIR\whateverplaceunder--input.dir\controlsfx.jar
```

Comment: Hi. That makes sense. I don't have the controlsfx.jmod, not sure it exists. I will try what you recommend when only having the .rar. Can you please add a little bit more information about the dependency part, not completely sure where to start :) I read that I don't have to pass any information about Controlsfx to JPackage?

Comment: Edit: Its working now, using what you recommended. Thank you very much.

Comment: `jlink` does not require JMOD files. As long as the JAR file has a `module-info` descriptor it will work just fine. You only need a JMOD file if you want to package things like native code and licenses along with your class files in a clean manner.

Comment: @droid You have `--add-modules javafx.controls,controlsfx` in your question, but the [module name](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/0a8caa4ad2abb3dea48fecb10819ea540748e308/controlsfx/src/main/java/module-info.java#L31) for _ControlsFX_ is `org.controlsfx.controls`.

Comment: @Slaw that is useful info about jmod files, I shall amend my answer.

Comment: I just tried again with the correct package name and this time JPackage runs fine and the installed program also works fine. Thanks. I learned a lot.

Comment: @droid Sorry to be pedantic, but you used the wrong **module** name, not the wrong _package_ name. Regardless, I'm glad you got it to work :)