# can't run .jar file /java.jar: line 1: public: command not found

Tags: java, linux, jar

I have Ubuntu 16.04.

and downloaded a JDK with a tar.gz file extension and followed [This wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux) to install it.

When I try to run a .jar game (like Minecraft) It works successfully, and I have netbeans downloaded that is connected to the same JDK and compiled some programs that i can run in terminal, But When I type :

`./Hello_world.jar`

Which is :

```
package main;

public class project {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello world");
   }  
}
```

I get this output :

```
./Hello_world.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
./Hello_world.jar: line 2: $'\b.\020oK': command not found
./Hello_world.jar: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./Hello_world.jar: line 3:-oK�}����META-INF/MANIFEST.MFM�1
                                                        �0��@��uHh          Q���X� ��N1�Ҧ$)��7�(�p�ww
�A����|��}�1���ή�n��p<�Рŗ��:CpN~�s�ν�˚�3��%
                                                 ��)���goPK`
```

Comment: If java is on the path, try it like this : java -jar Hello_World.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: JAR files aren't executables. You can only **invoke** binaries/scripts by telling your shell to `./command`.

They are **archives** that contain compiled Java classes.

Thus you use them like:

```
java -jar somejar.jar
```

This starts a java virtual machine, and tells it to open the given JAR file. The JVM will then figure the "main" class to run from the meta information that can be backed into the JAR file - to then "run" that main class.

( assuming that the corresponding JAR file has been built in a why that allows running it like this. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file) for details on how you enable this "easy way" of running a JAR file )

And just in case: with some scripting magic, you actually can turn a JAR file into a "binary", see [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa/how-to-make-a-jar-file-linux-executable) for example.