# How to run a class with main method?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a simple class with a main method. This is not my main class in the application but a tool. I want to run it like

```
java -cp mySpringBoot.jar com.pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.mytool
```

I can see that this class is in there in the same package but under `BOOT-INF/classes/com/pkg1/pkg2/pkg3/mytool.class`

I tried using the `BOOT-INF/classes` folder as well but it keeps saying

`Error: Could not find or load main class ... com.pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.mytool`
Edit:
My tool class that is inside the spring boot jar is very simple, it is not in the same package as the root where my SpringBootApplication class resides.

```
package com.comp.mypackage.tools;

//imports
public class MyTool{

public static void main (String args[]) {
......
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your class mytool.java source?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this stackoverflow post [How to run a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)

It will show you how to use a manifest file (where you define your main method), how to package (create) the jar, and run the jar.

Comment: I know how to do that in a normal Jar. thank for the link.; But i want to do it in a Springboot jar which already has a main class and spring boot writes to the manifest file. Even in a normal jar you can do java -cp myjar.jar  com.mypackage.myclasswithmain and it runs. but in spring boot it does not. If you do java -jar myjar.jar to a spring boot it runs the class in the manifest.

Comment: The only way I know of running a "main method", in a Spring Boot JAR, is to use a manifest file.  I've added another answer to illustrate this.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot creates a "fat JAR" with maven (with all depenedencies).  For an example, if you go to the Spring Boot guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/

Clone the git repo.  mvn package (which creates the JAR file).  Look in the JAR file - inside "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".  There is a "Main-Class: hello.HelloWorld", which defines the package, class to run:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-maven.git
cd gs-maven/complete

mvn package
cd target/
jar xvf gs-maven-0.1.0.jar
less META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

-----
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: ********
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.2
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Main-Class: hello.HelloWorld
```