# spring boot - no main artifact

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created a *Spring Boot* application, I have build the project and selected the main class and I have also added properties in my [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/76kE89FJ):

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.mua.scraper.ScraperApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
```

Now the problem is when I try to run the `.jar` file, it tell me that `MainClassNotFound`. Here is a snap:

[image: main class not found - spring boot]

Later project will be opend [here](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Web-Scraper)

After changing the command, here is my output:

[image: no main artifact]

Error:

**No main artifact**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was in my artifact, so here is what I have done:

- Opened `Project Structure`(*CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S*)
- Navigate to `Artifacts -> JAR ->  From module with dependencies`
- Then Selected `Main` class, or the entry class
- Copy the output directory and link via manifest(**I made the mistake here**)
- Don't forget to select that directory as in the picture

[image: step 1,2-spring build jar]

[image: step 3,4-spring build jar]

Answer (score 2):

You are missing -jar to properly run the jar file. It should be:

```
java -jar scrapper.jar
```

Comment: And use `./mvnw package` to generate an executable jar instead of `./mvnw jar:jar`.

Comment: @azizunsal can you describe a little please ?

Comment: It is needed to run `./mvnw spring-boot:repackage` to create an executable jar indeed. Since you added the `execution` goal under `build` plugin, `repackage` is applied after Maven `package` phase. So the resulting jar is an executable one (*the fat jar*), and you can run it by typing `jar -jar target/scrapper.jar`.