# NIFI ExecuteStreamCommand: execute Java code on windows

Tags: java, windows, apache-nifi

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file), I'm trying to execute Java code on Windows using Nifi's ExecuteStreamCommand processor

[image: ExecuteStreamProcessor configuration]

I get the following error (Java could not load or find the main class):

> Executable command java ended in an error: Erreur : impossible de
>   trouver ou charger la classe principale  -jar test.jar

Running `java -jar test.jar` on the command line works just fine

Test.java:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Maniphest file:

```
Manifest-version: 1.0
Main-Class: Test
```

Nifi version: 1.11.0

Thx in advance

Comment: I think just change argument delimiter to space symbol or replace space between _-jar_ and _test.jar_ with _;_ symbol in arguments.

Comment: That solved the problem ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yury Nevinitsin suggested, changing argument delimiter to space symbol solved the issue

> Command Arguments: The arguments to supply to the executable
>   delimited by the ';' character.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/