# How to execute JAR file

Tags: java, jar

```
                               MyProject
                               /       \
                        classes         source
                      /    |   \             \
            MyApp.class    |   app.jar       MyApp.java
                     manifest.txt
```

I have app.jar inside of classes folder. Now I want to execute the app.jar file.
but when i run using "java -jar app.jar", I got error "no main manifest attribute, in app.jar".
Tell me Why am I getting this error? and How to execute this JAR file.

Comment: Hi, Sagar. Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file

Comment: How, exactly are you trying to run this JAR file? Are you doing it programmatically from within your project, or are you trying to run it from command line?

Comment: I am trying to run it using command line.