# Not being able to run jar executable file

Tags: java, file

I downloaded `jdk-8u261-windows-x64.exe` and installed it. After the installation it produced a folder named `Java` inside `C:\Program Files`.

Inside `Java` folder there were two new folders. One was for `jdk` and the other was for `jre`. I added `jdk's bin` location to the `Path Environment Variable` and tried executing the jar file of one software. But, the jar file was still naked like there was no any program icon in it. Then I tried running it but it didn't show any programs that can execute the jar file.

I'm doing this in windows 10. What am I missing here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not even remotely related to programming, but to using a specific operating system.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such magic like opening a *.txt file in your preferred text editor. Running a jar file needs the command line:

```
java -jar my.jar
```

And the jar file must contain a manifest which indicates the main class to load.

See also [this SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)