# How build and run a java project with maven en .jar

Tags: java, maven, build, jar

I wouldlike execute my javaproject with "java crypter-v1.jar"
but i have "Error: Could not find or load main class Crypter-V1.jar"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp5f2.png)

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file

Comment: java -jar file.jar

Answer (score 0):

Add main class to MANIFEST.MF (replace with your package):

```
MANIFEST.MF

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: *package*.ClassWithMain
```

Then run

```
jar cfm crypter-v1.jar MANIFEST.MF *package*/
```

Then run it as

```
java -jar crypter-v1.jar
```