# How can I make .jar files to run on my computer?

Tags: java, jar, windows-10

I've searched for a while for a fix, I think I've tried all of the common fixes, I even tried Jarfix. I have JRE installed, and I deleted and reinstalled it again just to make sure, I'm running Windows 10 64 bit. If I double click the .jar just nothing happens, and I've made sure that .jar is set to open with the right file. I don't know what to try so if you have **any** suggestions, I'll try them, because I'm completely lost.

Whenever I try to run any command starting with "java" is gives me this: `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Add your JRE to the `PATH` of Windows.
When you add it there, running java commands in the command line, will be recognized since JRE will also be indexed.

This is how you add it:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\path\to\jre\bin\here
```

An example:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\bin
```

Then go to the folder where your `jar` file is located. And open a command line there.

Or go there through the `cd` command (which means change directory to jump to exactly this directory). Example:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\bin
```

And then run your `jar` this way:

```
java -jar yourJarName.jar
```

Comment: when i tried to run the jar, i got this ```C:\Users\daaaw\Desktop\jar> java -jar backpacked-1.10.1-mc1.16.3.jar
no main manifest attribute, in backpacked-1.10.1-mc1.16.3.jar```

Comment: Good news, your java installation works. Now you have a complete other problem... is this jar compiled by you?

Comment: no, it is not, :1

Comment: From googling I see that this jar is a Minecraft mod. This jar does not have a `main` function. Meaning that this jar was not meant to be run... I do not know how minecraft mods can be installed/put to use. That you have to research yourself.

Answer (score 0):

.jar files have the java directory directly inside of them so you shouldn't have to reinstall JRE.

Maybe your .jar file you are trying to run isn't put together properly.

OR there is nothing to run on your file or there is an error in the code.

Those are all ways it could be broken.

Comment: could be, but so far every .jar file I've tried has had the same issue, another thing I've thought of is if the version of java could have something to do with it, right now I have the latest version of JRE, and I didn't think .jar files could be version locked to where certain .jar files could only be opened with certain versions of java, but I could be wrong. thoughts?

Comment: the jar files already have the java version built into them.