# Having trouble executing my program from a jar, using Jinput

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, classpath, jinput

When I run my program from the IDE, it executes as expected and I don't see any errors in the log. The problem occurs when I try to run the artifact jar from the batch file.

I have a run configuration to execute the jar and I also have a windows .bat file. My end goal is to have the bat file execute the program for me.

Here is the source code for the entry point in the application. (launcher.ArcadeLauncher)

```
package launcher;

import launcher.framework.util.Logger;
import launcher.menu.MenuGame;

import java.io.*;

public class ArcadeLauncher {
    public static final String PROP_LIBRARY_PATH = "net.java.games.input.librarypath";
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        Logger.info(ArcadeLauncher.class.getSimpleName() + " started.");

        final String libraryPath = new File("src/main/resources/lib").getAbsolutePath();

        System.setProperty(PROP_LIBRARY_PATH, libraryPath);

        System.load(libraryPath + File.separator + "jinput-dx8_64.dll");
        System.load(libraryPath + File.separator + "jinput-raw_64.dll");

        final Thread gameThread = new Thread(new MenuGame());
        gameThread.start();

        try {
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        Logger.info(ArcadeLauncher.class.getSimpleName() + " complete.");
    }
}
```

Relevant project screenshots
[A screenshot of my project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cqAN.png)
[Run configuration the works from IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqjke.png)
[Run configuration tat suddenly started working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUbWH.png)

The batch file I plan to use to execute the jar.

```
@echo off
Title ArcadeLauncher - No Arguments

REM Set the directories for your libraries and classes
set "LIB_DIR=resources\lib"
set "CLASS_DIR=src\main\java"
set "MAIN_CLASS=launcher.ArcadeLauncher"

REM Create a classpath including the .jar files in the lib directory and the directory containing your compiled .class files
set "CP=%CLASS_DIR%;%LIB_DIR%\*"

REM Run the application
java -cp "%CP%" %MAIN_CLASS%

pause
```

When the batch file is run I get the following error. (Still not working)

```
Error: Could not find or load main class launcher.ArcadeLauncher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: launcher.ArcadeLauncher
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I was expecting no errors.I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the batch file and I suspect it's related to the classpath. I could use some help here.

I tried looking for similar issues on stack overflow, I made extensive use of chat-GPT as well. That got me to where I am now. I would appreciate the assistance./

Comment: If you are trying to run a jar, why does your class path not include the jar?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file

Comment: `final String libraryPath = new File("src/main/resources/lib").getAbsolutePath();` this obviously can't work. It's called `src` for a reason. You can't load DLLs from inside jars. You will have to do quite a bit of work: Read the DLL out using `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/lib/mything.dll")`, copy it somewhere on the file system, then load it. That, or make an installer than ensures that DLL is not in the jar but next to it.

Comment: Then ,you included your __source__ dir in your classpath which does, obviously, nothing. You need to include that dir that contains your class files. Or, the jar file. (Not 'the dir that contains the jar file'). You may want to follow a basic tutorial on getting a 'hello world!' app working as a jar before moving on to the considerably more complex scenario where you need native libs, like you do here.

Comment: I'd suggest `java -cp "%CP%" %MAIN_CLASS%` should be `java -cp "%CP%" "%MAIN_CLASS%"` - otherwise `launcher` and `ArcadeLauncher` are seen as two separate parameters - but I'm clueless about java parameters. Perhaps it would assist if you were to provide the full path for `lib_dir` and `class_dir`

Comment: Thanks  tgdavies. Your suggestion on extracting the jars into a temp directory and then loading them seemed to do the trick.